# C generate copies of a function by shifting its evaluation point

Tags: c, function, pointers

I am writing a C program to simulate jump processes. In some cases, the rates of jumping between different states are easy to calculate from a common function by shifting its evaluation point. So I would like to be able to take a given function pointer and shift and assign a function pointer which represents a shifted version of the original function.

After an hour online search, I have not found a solution and I am pretty convinced that this actually just not in the scope of traditional C. Does anyone have a work around or an idea for a different approach to take the original function and have access to shifted versions?

Below a minimal example, feel invited to get the test green :)

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

int f(int x) {
    return x;
}


void get_shifted_funtion(int (*pOriginalFunction)(int), int (*pShiftedFunction)(int), int shift) {
    ??? 
}

TEST(FunctionTest, GenerateAShiftedVersionOfAGivenFunction) {
    int (*fp)(int);
    int (*sfp)(int);
    fp = f;
    int shift = 2;
    int test_value = 0;
    get_shifted_funtion(fp, sfp, shift);
    EXPECT_EQ(fp(test_value+shift), sfp(test_value));
}
```

---

Edit: Implementation of the proposal by @MSalters to show a C way of solving the problem. Happy to hear about suggestions to improve this.

```
typedef struct STATEFUL_FUNCTION {
    int (*fp) (int);
    int shift;
} stateful_function;

int evaluate(STATEFUL_FUNCTION func, int input) {
    return func.fp(input + func.shift);
}

int test_function(int x) {
    return x;
}

TEST(FunctionTest, GenerateAShiftedVersionOfAGivenFunction) {
    int test_input = 0;
    int shift = 2;
    STATEFUL_FUNCTION sf = {test_function, shift};

    EXPECT_EQ(test_function(test_input+shift), evaluate(sf, test_input));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Won't work. C functions are stateless. Normally you'd solve that by creating a structure with two members, a function pointer and the desired state. In this case, I'm not sure why you would even want to store a function pointer in the first place. You're always calling the same function (right?) so all you need to store is that evaluation point.

Comment: It is a little bit a self-generated problem. I designed a structure to describe a jump process, which hold an array of reactions and each reaction holds a function pointer to calculate the current rate of this reaction. Now in the case of the particular jump process I want to study, I would like to avoid to explicitly stating all this functions, because they follow from a single function and state dependent shifts.

Comment: But I think, this dead end is just a sign for a design of the jump process structure which is not very user friendly, and I will try to rethink it.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I'm not sure what you mean by "shifted", but judging by the fact that it sounds like you want state to your function pointers, I've come across a post recently that might be interesting to you:
http://nullprogram.com/blog/2017/01/08/

It does however require programatically writing assembly to executable memory, which means it's not a pure C solution (not portable).

Hope this helped, good luck :)

Comment: Shifting: Given f:int -> int, I would like to have a pointer to g, with g(x) = f(x+c). Thanks, very interesting source, but shows that this is a rather complex approach :)